# How to write unit test for http request in golang?

Tags: unit-testing, http, go

I don't know how to test the http response given in the code below.

```
func getVolDetails(volName string, obj interface{}) error {
    addr := os.Getenv("MAPI_ADDR")
    if addr == "" {
        err := errors.New("MAPI_ADDR environment variable not set")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    url := addr + "/path/to/somepage/" + volName
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if resp != nil {
        if resp.StatusCode == 500 {
            fmt.Printf("VSM %s not found\n", volName)
            return err
        } else if resp.StatusCode == 503 {
            fmt.Println("server not reachable")
            return err
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("server not reachable")
        return err
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(obj)
}
```

With the help of some references i wrote unit test for this which is given below

```
func TestGetVolDetails(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        volume v1.Volume
        server *httptest.Server
    )
    tests := map[string]struct {
        volumeName string
        err        error
    }{
        "TestOne": {"vol", nil},
    }
    for name, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            response := `{"metadata":{"annotations":{"vsm.openebs.io/targetportals":"10.98.65.136:3260","vsm.openebs.io/cluster-i    ps":"10.98.65.136","openebs.io/jiva-iqn":"iqn.2016-09.com.openebs.jiva:vol","deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"1","openebs.io/storage-pool"    :"default","vsm.openebs.io/replica-count":"1","openebs.io/jiva-controller-status":"Running","openebs.io/volume-monitor":"false","openebs.io/r    eplica-container-status":"Running","openebs.io/jiva-controller-cluster-ip":"10.98.65.136","openebs.io/jiva-replica-status":"Running","vsm.ope    nebs.io/iqn":"iqn.2016-09.com.openebs.jiva:vol","openebs.io/capacity":"2G","openebs.io/jiva-controller-ips":"10.36.0.6","openebs.io/jiva-repl    ica-ips":"10.36.0.7","vsm.openebs.io/replica-status":"Running","vsm.openebs.io/controller-status":"Running","openebs.io/controller-container-    status":"Running","vsm.openebs.io/replica-ips":"10.36.0.7","openebs.io/jiva-target-portal":"10.98.65.136:3260","openebs.io/volume-type":"jiva    ","openebs.io/jiva-replica-count":"1","vsm.openebs.io/volume-size":"2G","vsm.openebs.io/controller-ips":"10.36.0.6"},"creationTimestamp":null    ,"labels":{},"name":"vol"},"status":{"Message":"","Phase":"Running","Reason":""}}`
            server = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                fmt.Fprintln(w, response)
            }))
            os.Setenv("MAPI_ADDR", "http://"+server.URL)
            if got := GetVolDetails(tt.volumeName, &volume); got != tt.err {
                t.Fatalf("GetVolDetails(%v) => got %v, want %v ", tt.volumeName, got, tt.err)
            }
            defer server.Close()
        })
    }
}
```

Where response is the response i'm getting from the server. This gives me always different errors.
`got invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value, want <nil>`

`got Get http://www.HugeDomains.com: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers), want <nil>`

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Updated the code with SOME_ADDR to MAPI_ADDR which was done while posting question. Please don't be confused with that, problem remains as it is.

Comment: For one thing, your test sets `MAPI_ADDR`, while your code reads `SOME_ADDR`. Unless `http://www.HugeDomains.com` (which is in your error message) is hostfiled to localhost, the test is not hitting the test server.

Comment: @Adrian that is my mistake, actual code is different from here...SOME_ADDR is MAPI_ADDR. How the testserver url can be redirected to localhost.

Comment: Then please post the actual code.

Comment: This is the actual code with only change in key that is MAPI_ADDR

Comment: Which is it? "This is the actual code" or "actual code is different from here"?

Comment: This is the actual code Sir.

Comment: Then I stand by my original comment. You're not using the same env var in the test and the code, leading to the error you're getting about trying to reach some domain instead of trying to reach localhost.

Comment: Sir i made that mistake in posting the question and i'm not able to edit it now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are getting a timeout but you are not specifying what `timeout` is set to. I suspect that this is not a time.Duration object and that is causing your timeout.  There are a few other issues as well. To get this to work I did:

1. Change the function being called in the test to `getVolDetails` to match the code (not the lower case `g`)
2. Set the `Timeout` when creating the `client` to `Timeout: time.Second * 10`
3. Remove the `"http://"+` from the `os.Setenv("MAPI_ADDR", "http://"+server.URL)` line

Corrected code is:

```
var timeout time.Duration = time.Second * 1000

func getVolDetails(volName string, obj interface{}) error {
    addr := os.Getenv("MAPI_ADDR")
    if addr == "" {
        err := errors.New("MAPI_ADDR environment variable not set")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    url := addr + "/path/to/somepage/" + volName
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if resp != nil {
        if resp.StatusCode == 500 {
            fmt.Printf("VSM %s not found\n", volName)
            return err
        } else if resp.StatusCode == 503 {
            fmt.Println("server not reachable")
            return err
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("server not reachable")
        return err
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(obj)
}
```

and test:

```
func TestGetVolDetails(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        volume v1.Volume
        server *httptest.Server
    )
    tests := map[string]struct {
        volumeName string
        err        error
    }{
        "TestOne": {"vol", nil},
    }
    for name, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
            response := `{"metadata":{"annotations":{"vsm.openebs.io/targetportals":"10.98.65.136:3260","vsm.openebs.io/cluster-i    ps":"10.98.65.136","openebs.io/jiva-iqn":"iqn.2016-09.com.openebs.jiva:vol","deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"1","openebs.io/storage-pool"    :"default","vsm.openebs.io/replica-count":"1","openebs.io/jiva-controller-status":"Running","openebs.io/volume-monitor":"false","openebs.io/r    eplica-container-status":"Running","openebs.io/jiva-controller-cluster-ip":"10.98.65.136","openebs.io/jiva-replica-status":"Running","vsm.ope    nebs.io/iqn":"iqn.2016-09.com.openebs.jiva:vol","openebs.io/capacity":"2G","openebs.io/jiva-controller-ips":"10.36.0.6","openebs.io/jiva-repl    ica-ips":"10.36.0.7","vsm.openebs.io/replica-status":"Running","vsm.openebs.io/controller-status":"Running","openebs.io/controller-container-    status":"Running","vsm.openebs.io/replica-ips":"10.36.0.7","openebs.io/jiva-target-portal":"10.98.65.136:3260","openebs.io/volume-type":"jiva    ","openebs.io/jiva-replica-count":"1","vsm.openebs.io/volume-size":"2G","vsm.openebs.io/controller-ips":"10.36.0.6"},"creationTimestamp":null    ,"labels":{},"name":"vol"},"status":{"Message":"","Phase":"Running","Reason":""}}`
            server = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                fmt.Fprintln(w, response)
            }))
            os.Setenv("MAPI_ADDR", server.URL)
            if got := getVolDetails(tt.volumeName, &volume); got != tt.err {
                t.Fatalf("GetVolDetails(%v) => got %v, want %v ", tt.volumeName, got, tt.err)
            }
            defer server.Close()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Iain Duncan your solution worked, i'm not able to upvote your answer though (Not 15 reputation yet) .

Comment: Great, pleased it worked @Utkarsh Mani Tripathi. You should be able to accept the answer if it is correct even without rotation and that'll give you a bit of reputation too!